# Whats the meaning of "advanced parental age"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Whats the meaning of **advanced parental age**

I know the dictionary meaning of *advanced* but this context

> In the presence of a genetic predisposition to autism, a number of nongenetic, or “environmental,” stresses appear to further increase a child’s risk. The clearest evidence of these autism risk factors involves events before and during birth. They include **advanced parental age** at time of conception (both mom and dad), maternal illness during pregnancy and certain difficulties during birth, particularly those involving periods of oxygen deprivation to the baby’s brain. It is important to keep in mind that these factors, by themselves, do not cause autism. Rather, in combination with genetic risk factors, they appear to modestly increase risk.

See for more http://www.autismspeaks.org/what-autism

Does it mean ***people who get children at his/her early ages?***  Check whether my interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 3):

It means the opposite - `advanced parental age` means people who have children older than most - depending on the doctor and study, that could be parents at least 35-40 years old.

Here's a study that sets it at 45 for fathers [Advanced parental age & Schizophrenia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2632511/)

and here's one that sets it at 40 for mothers: [Advanced maternal age and autism](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/02/100208102411.htm)